# How to get value from one modal window textbox and put it to another textbox in another modal window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reveal.js, modal-window

I would like to ask you guys for a little help. I wanted to have my textbox in a modal to have the same value in another textbox in another modal window. The problem is I don't know how. I'm new in using modal windows. Hoping that someone can help me.

```
Illustration:

Modal window1                  Modal Window 2
textbox1                      textbox2
```

*textbox1.value must be equal to textbox2.value upon typing. so when the modal window 2 comes out it must have already a value which is the value of Modal window1 textbox1.

Comment: Please show what you have so far.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can do this:

```
$('#textbox1').keydown(function(){
   $('#textbox2').val($(this).val());
});
```

I presume that you have two textboxes with id `textbox1` and `textbox2`.

I've attached `keydown` handler, which copies the `textbox1`'s value and assigns it to `textbox2` as you type.

Comment: This works well, but if only one modal window is visible at a time you could save some processing by having it only copy the value when the second modal window is shown. Still works this way though so +1.